# How to enable spinner in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I typed the html css code of the spinner but in javascript I can not activate the spin button
I want the rotate button to be activated with JavaScript but I do not know how

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Spinner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>spinner</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wheel">
        <div class="spinner" id="spinner">
            <div class="spin">
                <span class="one"><strong>1</strong></span>
                <span class="two"><strong>2</strong></span>
                <span class="three"><strong>3</strong></span>
                <span class="four"><strong>4</strong></span>
                <span class="five"><strong>5</strong></span>
                <span class="six"><strong>8</strong></span>
                <span class="seven"><strong>7</strong></span>
                <span class="eight"><strong>6</strong></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="rotatewheel" onclick="magicWheel()">Rotate</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its codes are also provided

Comment: this because `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >` and `<script src="script.js"></script>`doesn't exist !

Comment: put your script code in your question too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make a spinner, maybe you can take a look at [How TO - CSS Loader](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

You also can make a JavaScirpt-Control spinner yourself.

I made a Lock-Screen loader by use a `div` to cover  the whole screen.
Maybe you can refer it.
Like this.

```js
var loader = loader || {};

loader.show = async function (color, speed, text) {
  if (!color) {
    color = `#000000`;
  } else {
    const regexRule = /(?:#|0x)(?:[a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6})\b|(?:rgb|hsl)a?\([^\)]*\)/gi;
    let match = color.match(regexRule);
    if (!match) {
      color = `#000000`;
    } else {
      color = match[0];
    }
  }

  if (!speed) {
    speed = 2;
  }

  /* Set the style */
  let css = "";
  css += `.centered{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -6.25em;
    margin-left: -6.25em;
    z-index: 20;
  }`;
  css += `.loader{
    border:10px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:10px solid ${color};
    margin: auto;
    animation: spin ${speed}s linear infinite;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    opacity: 1.0;
  }`;
  css += `.textDiv{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius:0.25em;
  /*border: solid 1px black;*/
  background-color: #71836b;
  color: white;
  }`;
  css += `.background{
    background-color: #414141;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
  }`;
  css += `@keyframes spin{
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }`;

  let style = document.createElement("style");
  style.innerHTML = css;
  style.id = "loaderStyleId";
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  let topBody = document.body;
  let bodyContent = topBody.innerHTML;

  let backgroundDiv = document.createElement("div");
  backgroundDiv.setAttribute("id", "backgroundDiv");
  backgroundDiv.classList.add("background");
  topBody.appendChild(backgroundDiv);

  let loaderDiv = document.createElement("div");
  loaderDiv.setAttribute("id", "loaderDiv");
  loaderDiv.classList.add("centered");

  let spinner = document.createElement("div");
  spinner.classList.add("loader");
  loaderDiv.appendChild(spinner);

  if (text) {
    let textDiv = document.createElement("div");
    textDiv.innerText = text;
    textDiv.classList.add("textDiv");
    loaderDiv.appendChild(textDiv);
  }

  topBody.appendChild(loaderDiv);
};

loader.close = function () {
  let doc = document;
  let removeDiv = doc.getElementById("loaderDiv");
  removeDiv.remove();
  let backgroundDiv = doc.getElementById("backgroundDiv");
  backgroundDiv.remove();
  let loaderStyleId = doc.getElementById("loaderStyleId");
  loaderStyleId.remove();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>take a try to click here, when loader show</button>

<script>
function docReady(fn) {
    // see if DOM is already available
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // call on next available tick
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}
</script>

<script>
docReady(()=>{
  loader.show();
  //loader.close();
})
</script>
```

[An example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/s780609/pen/QWyjYJr), you can edit your spinner yourself.

#### Library

Or use **npm** to download [the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archer-loader).